# Correct method to send simple data using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, pebble-js

I have setup a basic Node.js server using express (WebStorm default), and have attempted to make it upon request (from a pebble watch) to run a python script, and send the returned json in the form:

```
{"willCollide": 1, "time": 6000, "strength": "NA"}
```

back to the watch. I have just started looking into JavaScript so have very little experience, and would expect I'm doing most of this incorrectly.
Currently I experience an "Error: can't set headers after they are sent" and was wondering what is the correct method to send a json to a user upon a request?
I am also wondering whether this is indeed the best method to go about sending the data from the python script to a Pebble watch.
Below is the code in the JavaScript file being called on the request:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

var options = {
    mode: 'json'
};

var rain_data;

function run_py_script(data){

    var pyshell = new PythonShell('dummy.py', options);
    var ret_val;
    /* Dummy data doesnt matter atm */
    pyshell.send("dummy data"); // change to data

    pyshell.on('message', function(message){
        console.log(message);
        ret_val = message;
        console.log(message["willCollide"]); // debug check
    });

    pyshell.end(function(err){
        if (err) {
            console.log('error received from python script');
        }
        console.log('finished script');
    });

    return ret_val;
}

/* GET rain_track data. */

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

    rain_data = run_py_script(null);

    res.write(rain_data);
    res.end();
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: What version of Express are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you're having trouble with asynchronous execution.

Your function `run_py_script(data)` does not return the final value until the `end` event is fired. Then, you'll be able to return the response back to the user.
Here you have two possible solutions:

1. Callbacks
2. Promises

I'm going to make an approach using a callback

First, `run_py_script` will have 2 arguments, `data` and a function to be called with the response, let's call it `cb`. `cb` will be called eventually with the final data.

```
function run_py_script(data, cb) {
  // I'm going to summarize this code 
  var ret_val;

  pyshell.on('message', function(message){ 
    ret_val = message; 
  });

  pyshell.end(function(err){ 
     return err ? cb(null) : cb(ret_val);
  });

  // note there is no return statement
}
```

Now, let's create your controller:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    run_py_script(null, function(rain_data) {
      res.json(rain_data); // same as write().end() but more elegant
    });
});
```

**Final bonus:** The node convention for `cb` is to be a 2 arguments function; the first argument uses to be an error which will be `null` is everything is ok, and the second argument is the data itself which will be `null` if error.

With this in mind the final code would be (summarizing)

```
function run_py_script(data, cb) {
  // ...
  pyshell.end(function(err){
    return err ? cb(err, null) : cb(null, ret_val);
  });
} 
run_py_script(null, function(err, rain_data){ 
  if (err){ return res.json(null); }
  return res.json(data);
});
```